# Get PHAssets based on "Face" metadata

Tags: ios, photokit, phasset

Using Photos in Mac users are able to tag people in photos. This data is then synced to the cloud where they can preform face searches in Photos on iOS. The type of metadata seems to be "Face". Is it possible to get all the assets associated with one of these faces? I'd like to grab all the images with a certain person in it. You are able to do it in the Photos search in iOS so my hope is that it is also open to other developers.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Apple released an SDK for accessing Apple Photos called Photo Kit. In the documentation, you will find API access to the photos application and photos cloud. However, if you are looking for an HTTP API I do not believe one has been announced publicly.

If you only need access to is data on Photos MacOS app I would recommend digging through the SQLite photos.db located in the photos library database directory.

```
/Users/[yourUserName]/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary/database/photos.db
```

I am working on a project this weekend that requires similar face data and will document my progress. Here is a sample SQLite query you can use to get all faces, photos, and corresponding person:

```
SELECT *, RKFace.modelId AS fId
FROM RKFace
JOIN RKMaster ON RKMaster.modelId = RKFace.imageModelId
LEFT JOIN RKFaceGroup ON RKFaceGroup.modelId = RKFace.faceGroupId
LEFT JOIN RKFaceCrop ON RKFaceCrop.faceId = RKFace.imageModelId
LEFT JOIN RKFacePrint ON RKFacePrint.faceId = RKFace.imageModelId
LEFT JOIN RKPerson ON RKPerson.modelId = RKFace.personId;
```

I hope this helps. :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is no API for that kind of stuff on iOS at the moment.